# how to make method for checkbox and call it in another method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just want to add this 2 lines in a method and call it in submitOrder method instead of placing them directly in submitOrder method .is it possible

```
CheckBox isCheckedWhipping = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_Whipped);

boolean checkWhippedCream= isCheckedWhipping.isChecked();
```

submitOrder method

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    CheckBox isCheckedWhipping = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_Whipped);

    boolean checkWhippedCream= isCheckedWhipping.isChecked();

    int price= calculatePrice();

    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(price,checkWhippedCream));
}
```

I try do this but not working

```
public boolean checkBoxWhipped(){

   CheckBox isCheckedWhipping = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_Whipped);

    boolean checkWhippedCream= isCheckedWhipping.isChecked();

    return checkWhippedCream;
}
```

call in  submitOrder method

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    boolean checkWhippedCream = checkBoxWhipped();

    int price= calculatePrice();

    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(price,checkWhippedCream));
}
```

thank you

Comment: What kind of issues are you having? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We need more information to answer this question. What are you trying to achieve? What is the error message / current behaviour?

Comment: @noha what type of error or exception you are getting?